# ScheduledExecutorService with variable delay

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice, blockingqueue

Suppose I have a task that is pulling elements from a java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue and processing them.

```
public void scheduleTask(int delay, TimeUnit timeUnit)
{
    scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Task(queue), 0, delay, timeUnit);
}
```

How can I schedule / reschedule the task if the frequency can be changed dynamically?

- The idea is to take a stream of data updates and propagate them in batch to a GUI
- The user should be able to vary the frequency of updates

Comment: it's not clear to me why you are using a blocking queue.
if youe queue is empty. I assume your scheduled task will be blocked. is that your intention? this will probably confuse the task scheduler timing.

Comment: I chose the ArrayBlockingQueue implementation as it has to be threadsafe, respect FIFO ordering and be bounded. Even if the task blocks, it shouldn't confuse the task scheduling should it?

Comment: You are correct in using a BlockingQueue implementation (in fact ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor uses one internally).  However, why are you propagating your updates to the GUI using a timer at all?  Why not do it in real-time?  Are there too many updates?  Are you concerned about the Swing thread spinning?

Comment: I want to batch the updates. So internally the events may arrive every ms, but the gui will refresh every 100ms. I think this will be more appealing visually and have less cpu overhead. I'm using Eclipse RCP instead of Swing.

Comment: Later duplicate: [*How do I change the rate or period of a repeating task using ScheduledExecutorService?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28620806/642706)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you can change a fixed rate delay. I think you need to use [schedule()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule%28java.util.concurrent.Callable,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) to perform a one-shot, and schedule again once that has completed (with a modified time out if required).

Comment: Thanks - I made 'delay' an instance variable and added a private method to do the following: while(!executorService.isShutdown) { executorService.schedule(new Task(queue), delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); }

Answer (score 38):

Use `schedule(Callable<V>, long, TimeUnit)` rather than `scheduleAtFixedRate` or `scheduleWithFixedDelay`.  Then ensure that your Callable **reschedules itself or a new Callable instance** at some point in the future.  For example:

```
// Create Callable instance to schedule.
Callable<Void> c = new Callable<Void>() {
  public Void call() {
   try { 
     // Do work.
   } finally {
     // Reschedule in new Callable, typically with a delay based on the result
     // of this Callable.  In this example the Callable is stateless so we
     // simply reschedule passing a reference to this.
     service.schedule(this, 5000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
   }  
   return null;
  }
}

service.schedule(c);
```

This approach avoids the need to shut down and recreate the `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Comment: Instead of `Callable<Void>` you can (should?) use `Runnable`.

Comment: I don't find the `schedule(Callable)` function for a ScheduledExecutorService. Only the ones with all parameters. Could you please point me to where? Or at least fixed the example to include a delay of 0.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule-java.util.concurrent.Callable-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-

Answer (score 6):

I had to do this recently using ScheduledFuture and didn't want to wrap Runnable or such. Here's how I did it:

```
private ScheduledExecutorService scheduleExecutor;
private ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleManager;
private Runnable timeTask;

public void changeScheduleTime(int timeSeconds){
    //change to hourly update
    if (scheduleManager!= null)
    {
        scheduleManager.cancel(true);
    }
    scheduleManager = scheduleExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(timeTask, timeSeconds, timeSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

public void someInitMethod() {

    scheduleExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);    
    timeTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //task code here
            //then check if we need to update task time
            if(checkBoxHour.isChecked()){
                changeScheduleTime(3600);
            }
        }
    };

    //instantiate with default time
    scheduleManager = scheduleExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(timeTask, 60, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you be using `scheduleAtFixedRate` if you are trying to process several queue tasks with a specific interval? `scheduleWithFixedDelay` will only wait for the specified delay and then execute one task from the queue.

In either case, the `schedule*` methods in a `ScheduledExecutorService` will return a `ScheduledFuture` reference. If you want to change the rate, you can cancel the  `ScheduledFuture` and reschedule the task with a different rate.

Comment: scheduleWithFixedDelay(...) - Creates and executes a periodic action that becomes enabled first after the given initial delay, and subsequently with the given delay between the termination of one execution and the commencement of the next. If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent executions are suppressed. Otherwise, the task will only terminate via cancellation or termination of the executor.

Comment: Can you give a code example of cancelling and rescheduling? What about any updates in progress?

Answer (score 0):

scheduleWithFixedDelay(...) returns a RunnableScheduledFuture. In order to reschedule it, you might just cancel and reschedule it. To reschedule it, you may just wrap the RunnableScheduledFuture wit a new Runnable:

```
new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ((RunnableScheduledFuture)future).run();
    }
};
```