# How do i have java wait a second before executing the next line, without try/catch

Tags: java, try-catch, wait

I am wondering if there is a way to do this, without anything confusing or messy. 
also, when i do a `wait()` method, it has a `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException` error.

Comment: `wait` probably doesn't do what you expect. Anyway, you need `Thread.sleep()`. If you don't want to mess with that try-catch stuff, just put it in a utility-method and call it `saveSleep` or something

Comment: Would you find nay luck [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519091/scheduledexecutorservice-with-variable-delay)

Comment: Search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 4):

The `Thread.sleep()` method can do what you want. It's a simple approach that stops execution for a given amount of time (not always accurate). Per the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html):

> Thread.sleep causes the current thread to suspend execution for a specified period. This is an efficient means of making processor time available to the other threads of an application or other applications that might be running on a computer system.

So, to call it, use,

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

This will sleep for one second until further execution. The time is in milliseconds or nanoseconds.

This method may not always be accurate due to the OS and its configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Once again, [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) is your friend:

```
Uninterruptibles.sleepUninterruptibly(1,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

and this is how it is implemented:

```
 public static void sleepUninterruptibly(long sleepFor, TimeUnit unit) {
    boolean interrupted = false;
    try {
      long remainingNanos = unit.toNanos(sleepFor);
      long end = System.nanoTime() + remainingNanos;
      while (true) {
        try {
          // TimeUnit.sleep() treats negative timeouts just like zero.
          NANOSECONDS.sleep(remainingNanos);
          return;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          interrupted = true;
          remainingNanos = end - System.nanoTime();
        }
      }
    } finally {
      if (interrupted) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      }
    }
  }
```

br

Answer (score 1):

In Java

```
Thread.sleep(intervalInMills);
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(intervalInMills);
```

Timer

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(task, delay, period);
```

With Executor Framework

```
ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable command, long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit)
```

With Spring,

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
private void method() {
    // some code
}
```

You can also schedule `cron` or `fixedRate` with `initialDelay`.

Answer (score 0):

Without Thread and try/catch:

```java
static void pause(){
    long Time0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long Time1;
    long runTime = 0;
    while (runTime < 1000) { // 1000 milliseconds or 1 second
        Time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        runTime = Time1 - Time0;
    }
}
```

**Update:**

[awilkinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3590534/awilkinson) is right, the above method is a really bad hack. By the way, if you just want a ready to use method to wait for a second or more, even if it uses try/catch, then I would recommend this:

```java
public static void pause(double seconds)
{
    try {
        Thread.sleep((long) (seconds * 1000));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}
```

Comment: This approach should not be used because it will continually execute the loop using CPU cycles for the full wait time.